# Regex to search inside contents of file

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using software to search inside txt files with Regex, For example
[image: Screenshot of my txt file as a example]

So I want to find files which Contain "Black" under "color" under "clothes", So the regex should highlight "Black" which located in line 7 only.
My aim here is to follow the order no mater how many lines between terms.

I will be more than thankful if you explain "regex" so I know what I have missed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: its much better to put them in XML File or Database table , and you query one of them in whatever language you choose

Comment: For starters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
You should probably think of a better way to define your data rather than just storing it in a text file, like XML.

Comment: This is not a job for regex. Use a parser instead.

Comment: if you have control over how this data is written, then i recommend storing it in a database as a hierarchical table or something. Regex is a hammer and I'm not sure this is a nail.

Comment: what the other commentators said, plus: your file already looks almost like yaml, so why don't convert to yaml and use a yaml parser in your programming language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)

Comment: Your file does not describe a regular language, therefore you can not user regular expressions alone to do what you want. You will have to write a parser.

Can you write something, or are you trying to use existing tools?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, but let me explain more.
this file is just simple txt file which I used to put inside my folders as "Tags". so If I want to find folder with tags I just use "http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro" to search inside those txt files then extract its path.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know anything about databases. I used those txt files as tags system for my local folders that's all.
any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: From the pro version:   Scripting

Search logic can be extended using JScript, VBScript or any other Active scripting language.   You probably need to learn some scripting.

Comment: Could you please Derek narrow options here, it will be hard for me to learn VBscripting over night, I just want to do specific mission. so If you could told me what I am searching for here (specific function) or whatever to create script which do what I want, it will be much easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex for matching the given 'Black':

```
/.+?Clothes.+?Colour.+?(Black)/s
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/gD9iD3

#### Discussion

The regex here may not fit all your needs. It uses `.+?` for navigating between the searched elements. This is really imprecise: the "Red" case that you have outputted in your comments is a guenine POC.

The next step here is to determine **how** elements (Clothes, Colour etc) are structured. Armed with this knowledge, the regex can be strengthened. `.+?` will be replaced then by more specific elements.

If the regex is used in a Javascript context, the `s` modifier is not available.
To work around this limitation, the following structure: `.+?` can be replaced with `[\s\S]+?`.

Comment: If the input file contains "Red" as color of clothes, then this regex will find still be true (because it matches the black color of the shoes). So this pattern alone will not solve the problem...

Comment: @slartidan I'm afraid I do not understand. Please add this new case ("Red") in your question and explain more what you expect...

Comment: @slartidan I have added a "Discussion" sectino to my answer for covering your last case and others...

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for :), But the real problem now that is s modifier not supported by Javascript Regex. I need this regex to be working with javascript Regex.

Comment: @user2132188 I have added a special note for Javascript at the bottom of my answer.